# Cartesian Product of two lists in F# using recursion and helper function

Tags: f#, product, cartesian

I am trying to get the cartesian product of two lists and I am getting an error that says that my function productHelp is not defined. I am not too sure how to solve this without having a helper function and I am not even sure if this would even work if it'd let me call my helper function.

```
let rec product A B =
    match A, B with
    | [], [] -> [ [] ]
    | e1::rest1, [] -> productHelp A B :: product rest1 B

let rec productHelp A B =
    match A, B with
    | [], [] -> [ [] ]
    | _, [] -> [ [] ]
    | e1::rest1, e2::rest2 -> [e1::e2]::productHelp A rest2


/home/codio/workspace/program/set/set.fs(144,24): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'productHelp' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the followi
ng:   product [/home/codio/workspace/program/set/set.fsproj]
    5 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Example:

```
// Example:
//   A = [1;2]
//   B = [3;4]
//   ==> [ [1;3]; [1;4]; [2;3]; [2;4] ]
//
```

Answer (score 3):

In F#, you must order your declarations within a file so that a declaration only refers to the ones above it. That is, declare the helper before the product function.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a [comprehension](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#Using_List_Comprehensions)?

```
let product A B = [for a in A do for b in B -> [a; b]]
```